# Batch Script to Automatically Open Modified Files

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm looking for a method which would allow me to automatically open a modified file in windows. In other words, something running in the background which detects changes in a given set of files; such that when one is detected, the file is opened. I attempted writing a batch file which saves the last modified date and time to a text file and repeatedly checks that. I think this method works, but I didn't know if there's a better way out there.

My motivation is that I'm scp'ing files regularly from a linux machine to windows, and it would be neat if they just opened automatically on my windows machine after updating locally.

Comment: The archive attribute is much better for this task. Every time, Windows writes to the file, the attribute is set. See the [attrib](https://ss64.com/nt/attrib.html) command for more information.

Comment: To build on @Stephan 's comment, you can also use the `DIR` command to list files with the archive attribute set. `DIR /AA /B`